# limit jquery get text(); to gather only for 10 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery's `.text()` method to get my text contents of div element. Which is fine & works fine, however, I am trying to come up with a method to allow ONLY to get `.text();` of first **10** text characters, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overriding jquery's `.text()` will show reflection everywhere.

So the best option would be create a function for doing this,

```
function myText($elem,len=10){
  return $elem.text().substr(0,len)
}
```

and call it like `myText($("#textWithElement"))`. Also you can alter your returning text's length by passing the second parameter `myText($("#textWithElement"), 5)`.

And due to the confusion happened in comment section, I would like to add some details about the usage of substr and substring at this context.

```
"string".substr(0,2) //where 0 is the start and 2 is the length
"string".substring(0,2) //where 0 is the start and 2 is the to (not inclusive)
```

So here in your context, both would yield the same result. But it is good to know about the difference between the both.

Comment: what if the OP wants to use this feature for only one time

Comment: @user1533609 Extracting whatever he wants from the answer, that is upto OP. But our duty is to suggest him best practices.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it the best practice for making a function for one liner code

Answer (score 2):

```
el.text().substring(0,10);
```

where `el` is a jquery element